# Can you create instances of two foreign keys referencing the same model in one model?

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I'm trying to create two instances of a model class called Team. I want to create two fields stored in my GameId Model called home and visitor. These two foreign keys are referenced from the same model called Team. Should I use a foreign key or many to many field relationship?

Background of models:

- One team can have many gameids
- One gameid should have 2 teams

  ```
  class GameId(models.Model):

      week = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
      day = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
      home = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, 
      related_name='home')
      visitor = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, 
      related_name='visitor')

      gameid = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a ***gameID*** can hold more than **1 team** then it is needed to be set to `ManyToMany`.

```
class GameId(models.Model):

    week = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    day = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    home = models.ManyToMany(Team, related_name='home')
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, 
    related_name='visitor')

    gameid = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot